# qt hasfeature transaction false on mysql innodb table

Tags: mysql, qt

It's on Win10 64 MySQL 5.7 Qt5.8.
Tables are using `InnoDB` Engine.Have the `libmysql.dll` there so the project can do CURD to the database.
But the `transaction()` return false so it's the `hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions)`;
Before and after them I checked by `select @@autocommit;` both turns 0.

Do I need some additional dependency?
Or something else I did wrong?

Comment: The problem was that you used the new version of libmysql.dll, try another version.

Comment: so which version should be right?